# why is http delete request not deleting the item

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-services, angular-http

The dropdown service calls the `http delete service` which gets the `id` from the data in the firebase server. and then sets that `id` to the property `idArr` in http service. then that `id` is used to delete the database entry. but its not working.

I was expecting the {data.id[0]} field in the database to be deleted but its not being deleted

No errors were thrown

// drop down service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ICourseModel } from '../interface/course-model';
import { HttpPostService } from './http-post.service';
import { HttpGetService } from './http-get.service';
import { HttpDeleteService } from './http-delete.service';


@Injectable()
export class DropDownService {
  courses: ICourseModel[] = [
    { course: 'Mobile Development' },
    { course: 'Web Development' },
    { course: 'IOS Development' },
    { course: 'Android Development' }
  ];
  id: string[];
  coursesDt: any = this.httpGet.getData();


  private setDt() {
    this.httpSer.storeData(this.courses).subscribe(
      (response) => { console.log(response); },
      (error) => { console.log(error); });
  }

  private getDt() {
    this.httpGet.getData().subscribe(
      (response) => { this.coursesDt = response; },
      (error) => { console.log(error); });
  }

  getData() {
    return this.courses;
  }

  setData(obj: { course: string }) {
    this.courses.unshift(obj);
  }
  constructor(private httpSer: HttpPostService, private httpGet: HttpGetService, private dlt: HttpDeleteService) {
    this.setDt();
    // this.getDt();
    console.log(this.coursesDt);
    this.dlt.gtData().then(id => { this.dlt.idArr.push(...id); });
    this.dlt.removeDt().then(() => console.log('ran'));
  }
}
```

// http delete service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpDeleteService {
  idArr = [];
  public baseUrl = '';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log(this.idArr);
  }

  gtData() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/data.json`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => this.convert(response.json()));
  }

  convert(pasrsedResponse) {
    return Object.keys(pasrsedResponse).map(
      id => (id)
    );
  }

  removeDt() {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.idArr[0]}.json`).toPromise();
  }
}
```

// app component

```
ngOnInit() {
    // form controls validation specicified in the class for the Reactive Forms
    this.courseForm = this.fb.group({
      username: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/)]],
      email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})')]],
      address: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      date: [null, [Validators.required]],
      select: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });
    // passing the observable to the variable which then uses async pipe
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => { this.coursesDp = data['course']; });


    this.personDetail = this.fieldData.getPersonData();
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: i was expecting the `{data.id[0]}` field in the database to be deleted

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Its looks there is an issue in your services which doesn't return the promise or observable.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ICourseModel } from '../interface/course-model';
import { HttpPostService } from './http-post.service';
import { HttpGetService } from './http-get.service';
import { HttpDeleteService } from './http-delete.service';


@Injectable()
export class DropDownService {
  courses: ICourseModel[] = [
    { course: 'Mobile Development' },
    { course: 'Web Development' },
    { course: 'IOS Development' },
    { course: 'Android Development' }
  ];
  id: string[];
  coursesDt: any = this.httpGet.getData();

  constructor(private httpSer: HttpPostService, private httpGet: HttpGetService, private dlt: HttpDeleteService) {
    // Then or subscribe cannot be attached here
    // Since this function doesn't return any promise or observable
    //this.setDt();

    // So take a look here we are calling another service in subscribe block.
    // I'm sorry I have to write this promise chain which looks ugly and mess.
    // Since your services are already in this way so I have to do it for simplicity 
    // and to be on the point.
    this.httpSer.storeData(this.courses)
      .map(resp => resp.json())
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.httpGet.getData()
          .map(resp => resp.json())
          .subscribe(response => {
            this.coursesDt = response;
            this.dlt.removeDt().then(() => console.log('ran'));
          });
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: would you please consider upvoting my question

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Upvoted your question. Since you found my answer helpful could you upvote my answer as well?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it is asynchronous. It boils down to:

```
constructor(private httpSer: HttpPostService, private httpGet: HttpGetService, private dlt: HttpDeleteService) {
    this.httpSer.storeData(this.courses);
    this.dlt.http.get('... url1 ...');
    this.dlt.http.delete('... url2 ...');
}
```

All these requests will be executing in parallel and there's no way to tell the order in which they will really be executed. So, when delete() gets run `idArr` is still empty. You need to chain calls in order to wait on the promise for the previous call has finished and only then start next call, something like this (code is not tested, just the idea):

```
constructor(private httpSer: HttpPostService, private httpGet: HttpGetService, private dlt: HttpDeleteService) {
    this.setDt().then(() => {
        this.dlt.gtData().then(id => { this.dlt.idArr.push(...id); }).then(() => {
            this.dlt.removeDt().then(() => console.log('ran'));
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: would you please consider upvoting my question